# reorganising data into prefix inside Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've a SQL tool for bigdata processing which dumps data into an Amazon S3 bucket in `.csv` files under the following prefix:

```
myS3Bucket
|
|__myTopPrefix
    |
    |_object1.csv
    |_object2.csv
    |_object3.csv
    |_object4.csv
    |_object5.csv
    |_object6.csv
```

My requirement is to further reorganise this data into sub-prefixes with following structure:

```
myS3Bucket
|
|__myTopPrefix
    |_subPrefix_1
    |   |_subSubPrefix_1
    |       |_object1.csv
    |       |_object2.csv
    |
    |_subPrefix_2
        |_subSubPrefix_2a
        |   |_object3.csv
        |   |_object4.csv
        |
        |_subSubPrefix_2b
            |_object5.csv
            |_object6.csv
```

The judgement of which object to put under which prefix is governed by looking at the header row in that object.csv file.

I'm allowed to use any Tool or (preferably)AWS service to achieve this but I don't know how to do it. I thought of using an `aws lambda` function to do this and read the documentation for lambda and other resources but couldn't get through. I'm new to AWS services and don't have deep understanding of them yet.

<strike>Update 1: number of entries in object.csv might be in billions, like 10-12 Billion.</strike>

**Update 2:** I've changed approach to my service and now "updated 1" is no more valid. The entries in any object.csv will now be around 10,000 but the object files that will be dumped in S3 in one execution of SQL script will now be increased to 12. Typical file size would be `150-200 MB` in worst case(which is never going to happen XD )

Also, I need this reorganising of objects to happen after every new object pushed to S3. And the prefix name(or the hierarchical path) I've already created but they don't hold any data/object initially.

As a workflow, I process data in my tool then dump it into `S3://myS3Bucket/myTopPrefix/` Now, that data should move to appropriate prefix based on information inside header of file. Job Done!

**Update 3:** For those who are thinking how 12 objects will be generated from a single SQL script: Basically in this tool, I can write several `select ... from ... where ...` and each query will output data as one object which is hardcoded(limitation of tool) to go under `S3://myS3Bucket/myTopPrefix/`. In current implementation, 12 objects will be generated in single execution of the SQL script.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you wish for this to happen whenever a new object is stored in S3 (ideal for an AWS Lambda function), or will it only be run on existing objects? Do the names `subPrefix_1` and `subSubPrefix_1` both come from the first line? Can you give us an example? What is the size of a typical file (I ask this due to limitations in disk space for Lambda functions)? Writing an AWS Lambda function sounds easiest, but just wanted to confirm the details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for taking time! I've updated the problem statement as `update 2` and `update 3`. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Do the names `subPrefix_1` and `subSubPrefix_1` both come from the first line? Can you give us an example? Particularly, how does it impact the CSV format of the headers? Or, is it something that is on _every_ line?

Comment: Would you consider putting new file in a specific path (eg `incoming/object1.csv`) and then moving the object to a separate path (eg `myTopPrefix/subPrefix_1/subSubPrefix_1/object1.csv`)? This will help avoid a situation where the newly copied object again triggers the Lambda function. It is much cleaner to keep the 'input' path totally separate to the 'output' path.

Comment: @johnRotenstein yes! I can take that also, though it's not structured that way yet, but if it works smoothly that way, than I'll use a separate prefix solely dedicated to incoming objects and then move them to other prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- You wish to move objects **at the time they are created** (no need to move historical objects)
- The name of the **target path** can be derived from the first line of each file
- The **input path is totally separate from the output path** (to avoid causing an infinite loop). For example, incoming files come in `input/` and are then moved to a path that does *not* start with `input/`.
- Amazon S3 has been configured to trigger the AWS Lambda function when a new object is created in the input path

Also, please note that Amazon S3 does not have a 'move' command. Instead, the objects need to be **copied then deleted**.

```py
import boto3
import urllib

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
    
    # Read the first line of the object
    # Uses iter_lines() to give us the first line from the StreamingBody without downloading the whole object
    object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    for line in object['Body'].iter_lines():
        line1 = line.decode('utf-8')
        
        # Extract information from first line here (this is just dummy code, put your code here)
        # Note that the directory does not need to exist already -- S3 does not need folders created
        destination_path = 'foo/bar/'
        
        # Break to exit loop, since we only want first line
        break
    
    # Copy object to new path
    filename = key[key.rfind('/')+1 : ] # Extract name after last slash
    destination_key = destination_path + filename
    
    s3_client.copy_object(
        Bucket=bucket,
        Key=destination_key,
        CopySource=f'{bucket}/{key}'
        )
    
    # Delete incoming object
    s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
```

Comment: yes! I can take those assumptions, though it's not structured that way yet, but if it works smoothly that way, then I'll use a separate prefix solely dedicated to incoming objects and then move them to other prefixes. 

Seem like this solution will work for my case, thanks again for taking time : )